# How to use msg_nosignal on mac osx

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I have a code which runs on mac osx or on linux and I want it to be portable, how do I make an #ifndef statement which switches `msg_nosignal` to the relevant flag under macosx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if it's being compiled on OS X, I think the main preprocessor directive for that is

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    ...
#endif
```